# php pass auto incremnt id in next page

Tags: php

I have a form where I insert a record and the ID (Primary key is Auto increment).
How I can show the ID in the next page after submit. I tried to echo `mysql_insert_id();` in next page but didnt work:

```
<?php echo "Your refrence number is = ". mysql_insert_id(); ?>
```

Comment: What "didn't work"? Show us your code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend, Let's see your issue this way. You have two pages A, and B. You insert data to the database in page A and get the last insert id with `mysql_insert_id();` Now the issue is you want to use this in page B. I can propose you 4 ways. but I will explain you session base way since I think it is the best solution for you.

1. POST
2. GET
3. Cookie
4. Session

Ok In your page A top of your page you write  `session_start();` remember it should be the first line. Once you get the last insert ID in page a you create a session variable.

```
$_SESSION["lastID"] = mysql_insert_id();
```

And in page B also you initiate the session as you did in page A. Then you can simply get the last ID using.

```
$lastID =  $_SESSION["lastID"];
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP `Session` variable. Put `mysql_insert_id()` in session after insert and access on next page.

```
$_SESSION["yourID"] = mysql_insert_id();
```

and access it on next page.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the last insert id in the the page where you insert the record, and then pass the the id to the next page (by url parameter).